# Can't access pure-ftpd

Tags: ftp, root

I've just compiled pure-ftpd (v1.33) using

./configure --with-pam --with-puredb

on my Mac mini Lion and pure-ftpd works fine but I can't access it

because of the authentication problem.

/usr/local/bin/pure-pw useradd root -u 0 -g 0 /private/var/root

tells me to give non-root uid and gid.

I want the ftp server to provide a root access, how can I achieve that?

BTW, interestingly on my Leopard Mac mini, I had compiled the same program 2 years ago and on it the pure-ftpd does accept the root user! (i.e. when I login the directory listed is /private/var/root and I do rwx rights to every folder on harddisk)

So I'm sure there must be a way to achieve this. I've browsed the /configuration-file/pure-ftpd.conf file and couldn't see something like 'AllowRoot' anyway I don't remember arranging any conf file on the Mac mini Leopard.

The last thing I want to note is that the root password I enter on ftp is different than the one on the OS's user root. A bit puzzling really.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

1- In Lion the PAM scheme is a bit different than Leopad, the /etc/pam.d/pure-ftpd file in particular. That's why the default pure-ftpd configuration in Lion didn't work. As a quick fix, you have to:

## cp /etc/pam.d/ftpd /etc/pam.d/pure-ftpd

i.e. you copy the Lions' default ftpd PAM scheme to pure-ftpd. It works.

2- For Lion, you have to install pure-ftpd-1.0.36, not 1.0.33 otherwise it hangs while trying to login to pure-ftpd.

3- Lastly, you have to set a password for the user you want to use. In my case I set for root (don't worry about the root access, the pure-ftpd is not open to Internet I use it solely inside LAN for development)

## passwd root (enter any password)

Because you can set any password here, your root password can be different from the Mac OS X's user with root privileges.