# pure-ftpd error: 530 Login authentication failed

Tags: homebrew, ftp

`pure-ftpd: stable 1.0.51`

`MacOS Catalina 10.15.7`

**Background:** I need to setup an FTP server in order to install OpenWRT on an old Dlink DIR300 router. I tried with a few different ftp servers and all were super hard to get to work for me, so I settled for pure-ftpd as it advertised being the easiest, but not in my case. 
I've done my bit of research and tried different workarounds but I still cannot get it to work.

`brew install pure-ftpd`

Then I ran `pure-pw useradd ftpuser -u ftp -d /User/mariano/srv/ftp` to create the user, followed by `pure-pw mkdb`

Just to be on the safe side, on `/usr/local/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` I've uncommented the following options:

```
PureDB                      /usr/local/etc/pureftpd.pdb
PAMAuthentication            yes
UnixAuthentication           yes
```

I've created `/etc/pam.d/pure-ftpd` with the following entries:

```
# pure-ftpd: auth account password session
auth       required       pam_opendirectory.so
account    required       pam_permit.so
password   required       pam_deny.so
session    required       pam_permit.so
```

then ran `sudo /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd -lpam -B`
and `brew services restart pure-ftpd` but when I try to log in I get this:

```
Connected to localhost.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 21:49. Server port: 21.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (localhost:mariano): ftpuser
331 User ftpuser OK. Password required
Password: 
530 Login authentication failed
ftp: Login failed.
```

So I googled and found [this blog about authentication issues](https://bobcares.com/blog/pure-ftpd-530-login-authentication-failed-on-directadmin-lets-fix-it/), and played around with the ownership of `/usr/local/etc/pureftpd.passwd` but also no luck.

I've also read [this AskDifferent question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117094/cant-access-pure-ftpd) but I don't have a `/etc/pam.d/ftpd` file to copy as suggested in the answer.

I've also followed [the instructions on this AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336441/set-up-ftp-server-on-macos-high-sierra-proftpd/336459#336459) but I had no luck.

I'm at loss, and also, I tried running `brew services start pure-ftpd -d` but I cannot find where the log is! The config file also does not allow to specify a log file , there's nothing on `/var/log/` or anywhere else that I can find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!